# Rails 5 - How Do You Split The find_or_create_by() Method Into Two Operations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am coming to Ruby / Rails from a PHP background.  I have an operation that looks like:

```
MyModelObject.find_or_create_by(user: object.provider)
```

In Laravel, I can more or less do the same thing by calling:

```
$user = MyModelObject::firstOrCreate(array(
    'id' => $user['id'],
    'name' => $user['name']
));
```

In this case, I'd like to split the above Laravel Eloquent call to:

```
$user = MyModelObject::find($user['id']);
if(is_null($user)){
    $user = MyModelObject::create(array(
        'id' => $user['id'],
        'name' => $user['name']
    ));
}
```

What's the equivalent of splitting this call into two in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: `model = MyModel.find_by(attributes) || MyModel.create(attributes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [create_with](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-create_with) to pass the attributes for new records separately from the attributes you are using to find the record:

```
User.create_with(name: params[:name])
    .find_or_create_by(id: params[:id])
```

Answer (score 1):

[`find_or_create_by`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/5.2.6/ActiveRecord/Relation#find_or_create_by-instance_method) accepts a block in which you can define attributes to assign to a new record that aren't used for finding the record. In this case, your code could look something like this:

```rb
user =
  User.find_or_create_by(id: 123) do |user|
    user.name = 'Example'
  end
```

(`123` and `'Example'` are placeholders.)

This will attempt to locate a `User` record with an `id` of `123`; if it can't find one, it will create a new `User` record with an `id` of `123` and a `name` of `'Example'`.